# Windows server 2003 x86 drivers issues

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, sata, windows-server-2003

I cannot install the ahci driver(32bit, sata) in win2k3 x86; says that the driver isn't 32 bit (but actually it is).

Also I cannot install the drivers for usb (usb mouse though works !?).

The system is trinity APU A10-5800K, asus fm2a85mpro. All the other drivers were ok, I used the win xp versions and everything ok but sata/usb.

Any ideas?

Comment: from what I see the board no longer supports this old Windows. Try at least Server 2008.

Comment: Use a motherboard that actually has drivers to support the Server OS you're trying to use, instead of that Desktop-level board. ;)

Comment: Nice one techie007! Credit goes to you as I downloaded the driver from an asus server motherboard (although I couldn't istall it properly, I had to use the manual method "have disk" option). It works but I worry about data corruption.. Any thoughts? But stil no USB3 (USB2 works fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 said, the trick was to use drivers from other motherboard.